# varnish is failed to get started

Tags: linux, centos, varnish

[root@neacdn1 system]# systemctl status varnish.service

● varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-07-11 15:38:34 CEST; 1min 7s ago
Process: 3607765 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m (code=exited, status=255)
Jul 11 15:38:34 neacdn1 systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Jul 11 15:38:34 neacdn1 varnishd[3607765]: Error: Could not get socket :6081: Address already in use
Jul 11 15:38:34 neacdn1 varnishd[3607765]: (-? gives usage)
Jul 11 15:38:34 neacdn1 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Jul 11 15:38:34 neacdn1 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 11 15:38:34 neacdn1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.

Answer (score 0):

> :6081: Address already in use

You should check what is running on 6081 port. Most likely, there is already a varnishd listening on 6081 port. Stop that process and try again.